# How do you import notepad files in python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am working on a triangle calculator ( It would find if a angle was acute, right, or obtuse.) and I want to use notepad to base it. 
example:

```
A = 3
B = 4
C = C
```

and it would modify the file so that :

```
A = 3
B = 4
C = 5
Your triangle is right!
```

Can anyone help clear this up for me?

Comment: Probably should just use a prompt for the user input rather then notepad. If you have to work in files use open('filepath') read and write to that file location.

Comment: The user interface you propose is very strange. I agree with @vikingben; use `raw_input` to prompt the user for data.

Comment: or pass on the command-line: `$ is-right-triangle A=3 B=4 C=B`

Comment: @vikingben Would you recommend a good prompt that i could use in this situation?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart gave you a pretty good example I'll just add the link for the documentation for the built in raw_input function. You can call this function with a question for your user such as please enter the length of your triangle side. Then you can use this to make your calculations. Then use the built in print function to give feedback to the user. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

Comment: @vikingben thank you

Comment: @theshover Not a problem let me know if you have any other questions and good luck!!

Comment: @vikingben since i follow py 3.x instead i use 'eval(input'